# Is it possible to shift table data to different cells with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a feature that involves adding content to the end of a table upon clicking a link to another page on the site. If there's already content at the end of the table, shift that content to the next cell and let the new content take its place.

For instance, after one action, add content to end,

```
<tr>
   <td id="cell_1"></td>                    
   <td id="cell_2"></td>                  
   <td id="cell_3"><span>Content</span></td>     <-- content
</tr>
```

And after another action, add more content and shift previous content,

```
<tr>
   <td id="cell_1"></td>                         
   <td id="cell_2"><span>Content</span></td>      <-- moved here
   <td id="cell_3"><span>New Content</span></td>
</tr>
```

Since I want this to happen on clicking a link to another page on the site, I was going to use cookies to write the data for every cell, then on the next page, load the data into the cells, shifted over one. There's only going to be 3-5 cells in my feature, so it's reasonable in terms of small amounts of data to handle, so I figured writing and reading cookies to and from cells was the most logical approach if I want it to persist through pages. But is there actually any better way to handle this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can pass table html to new page. Please refer below forum for this.

[https://forums.asp.net/t/1686492.aspx?Copy+HTML+table+and+pass+it+to+another+page](https://forums.asp.net/t/1686492.aspx?Copy%20HTML%20table%20and%20pass%20it%20to%20another%20page)

To shift the table cells, use the below code.

**1) Add content to end.**

$('#tblContent tr').append('New Content')

**2) Shift the cell:**

$('#tblContent tr td')[0].remove()